# Setting up view helpers

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I currently have the following setup in my module.

```
public function onBootstrap( EventInterface $e )
   {

      // You may not need to do this if you're doing it elsewhere in your
      // application
      $eventManager   = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

      $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

      $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
      $moduleRouteListener->attach( $eventManager );

      //TODO think about moving this to somewhere more appropriate
      $renderer = $serviceManager->get( 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer' );
      $renderer->headTitle( 'uDare' )->setSeparator( ' - ' );

   }
```

Is there a better way to do this or some other event that I should attach to?

I ask this because I'm hitting a problem when trying to use the Doctrine2ORMModule.

When I access the web page on my localhost all works fine. But when I run

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module --verbose
```

on the command line I get an error saying the following

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' 
with message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to 
fetch or create an instance for Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer' 
in /Library/WebServer/Documents/udare/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:407
Stack trace:
#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/udare/modules/Web/Module.php(56): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Zend\View\Rende...')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place for this probably would be in your `layout.phtml`.

If you need it to be configurable you could

1. Put it in your `layout.phtml`
2. Write your own view-helper acting as an adapter to this one
3. creating a custom factory for the `headTitle` view helper
4. wait until all view helpers are configurable by the service-manager - not only some of them. Have a look at `Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory` to get an idea about this.

I haven't tested 3. & 4. - I prefer 1. as this is a `view`/`phprenderer` specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

There have been recent merges into zf2 which change the way console requests are rendered. It seems those changes may have broken the DoctrineORMModule CLI. Please raise an issue on github, and it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem

i noticed that it caused by the new module that i installed "ZendDeveloperTools"

i removed it from module loading in my application.config.php file and error fixed

Comment: i don't have that module installed on my side. maybe they share some configuration settings?

Comment: try to disabling 3rd party modules in your config ... it may helps